# Javascript to format var_dump in pretty printed fashion for readability

Tags: javascript, php, json, pretty-print, var-dump

Can anyone provide an example script I can inject into my development site to make the nested output of `<pre><?php var_dump($rediculously_nested_variable); ?></pre>` easier to read? I am not familiar with any pretty-printing method for this.

Especially a script to make the nested parts fold and expandable would be great.

Comment: Ever try `json_encode()`?

Comment: I mean visually digest.

Comment: I'm hoping there's already a script for it.  If not, I'm going to have to take a few hours and perfect one for myself.  I'm hoping for a script that will just add a little dropdown triangle to expand/contract the output.

Comment: It's off topic, but check out [Krumo](http://krumo.kaloyan.info/)

Comment: @BGundlach, json_encode it parse it into the console and the console does that for you.

Comment: put it in nice triangles to pull down ;-)

Answer (score 1):

When I need pretty-printed JSON I usually use:

http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com

It requires a bit of copy paste, but it'll help you to get a grip on deep trees of data.

disclaimer: I'm not affiliated with the above website in any way.